# I'm getting the wrong output in my if statment

Tags: python

By default, it run the else-statement, but I don't understand why.

```
menu = "Baguette , Crossiant , Coffee , Tea , Cappuccino "
print(menu)
if "" > menu:
    order = input("What Would you like? \n ")
    amount = input("How many " + order + " would you like?")
    print( name + " Your " + amount + " " + order + " will be ready soon!\n\n\n")
    price = int(4)
    #converts number into intenger to do math correctly (int)
    total = price * int(amount)
    #turns total into string intead of intenger to prevent error in terminal
    print("Thank you, your total is: $" + str(total))
    print("Your " + amount + " of " + order + " is ready!")
    print("Please enjoy you " + order + "!")
    print("Please come again!")

else:
    #If not on menu stops running
    print("Sorry Thats not on the menu")
    quit()
```

Comment: what is `"" > menu` supposed to be doing?

Comment: if you think, there is anything on menu and you  have use `if ''>menu` for that, then you should be `if menu` that say that menu is true ie there are items on menu

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#input name
name = input("What is your name?\n")

#create menu
menu = "Baguette, Crossiant, Coffee, Tea and Cappuccino"

#display menu
print(menu)

#input order
order = input("What would you like?\n")

#if the order item is in the menu
if order in menu:
    
    #input quantity
    amount = input("How many " + order + "s would you like? ")
    
    #display message
    print( name + " Your " + amount + " " + order + " will be ready soon!\n\n\n")
    
    #setting price of all items to 4
    price = 4
    
    #calculating total
    total = price * int(amount)
    
    #turns total into string intead of intenger to prevent error in terminal
    print("Thank you, your total is: $" + str(total))
    print("Your " + amount + " of " + order + " is ready!")
    print("Please enjoy you " + order + "!")
    print("Please come again!")
#if the item is not in menu
else:
    #display message
    print("Sorry Thats not on the menu")
```

Hope this helps! I have added the explanation as comments.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
menu = ["Baguette" , "Crossiant" , "Coffee" , "Tea" , "Cappuccino "]
count = 0
for item in menu:
    print(str(count) +" -> "+str(item))
    count += 1
order = int(input("\n What Would you like? \n "))
if order > len(menu) or order < 0 or order == "" or not menu[order]:
    print("Sorry Thats not on the menu")
    quit()
orderCount = int(input("How many " + menu[order] + " would you like?"))
print("Your " + str(orderCount) + " " + menu[order] + " will be ready soon!\n\n\n")
amount = int(4) * int(orderCount)
print("Thank you, your total is: $" + str(amount))
print("Your " + str(amount) + " of " + str(menu[order]) + " is ready!")
print("Please enjoy you " + str(menu[order]) + "!")
print("Please come again!")
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. We should rather explain the challenge and how our solution tackles it.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not checking the user input, you are just checking for a False statement based on what you defined. You need to check if the user input is on the menu, else quit the program.

```
menu = "Baguette , Crossiant , Coffee , Tea , Cappuccino "
print(menu)
name = input("What your name? \n ")
order = input("What Would you like? \n ")
if not order.lower() in menu.lower(): # checking if user input is in the menu
    #If not on menu stops running
    print("Sorry Thats not on the menu")
    quit()

amount = input("How many " + order + " would you like?")
print( name + " Your " + amount + " " + order + " will be ready soon!\n\n\n")
price = int(4)
#converts number into intenger to do math correctly (int)
total = price * int(amount)
#turns total into string intead of intenger to prevent error in terminal
print("Thank you, your total is: $" + str(total))
print("Your " + amount + " of " + order + " is ready!")
print("Please enjoy you " + order + "!")
print("Please come again!")
```